# Three shaders (or more) sharing same basecolor?

Tags: shaders, color

Can I change BaseColor from one shader and update automatically in other SELECTED ONLY object's shaders at the same time to share the same basecolor?

[image: I Want to make sure the white shader keeps white in this case]

The idea is to use the same color on selected objects while respecting the other distinct properties of each shader

Thanks for help!

Comment: Sure :). Just create a nodegroup with a simple *RGB Node* and use it the materials you need synced

Comment: but do I have to include this nodeGroup in all shaders? Think of a scene with hundreds of shaders ...

Comment: Well, perhaps a script could help here, but that's outta my knowledge :).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! It will help in last case :)